# pip3 no longer working after installing Python 3.8

Tags: python, python3, pip

I installed python3.8 on my Ubuntu 18.04.4. Now `pip` is no longer working. When I try to install something it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pip.utils.glibc import libc_ver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

please help

Comment: How did you install `python3.8`?

Comment: i installed it with its source code with this command : ' ./configure 
    make 
    make test
    sudo make install '

Comment: Can you [edit] that information into your question? This will bump it back to the homepage so it gets visibility for other people to help. And please, add as much detail as you can so people can help you with your problem.